# Is there any way to load the GLTF file which is compressed by Draco?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gltf

I am looking for a way how to load the draco compressed .gltf on iOS.
I am using [GLTFSceneKit](https://github.com/magicien/GLTFSceneKit) to render the gltf file which is exported by Blender. But if I compress the .gltf files with draco/ [gltf-transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/index.html), the render doesn't work anymore.

Please let me know if you know any help!

Comment: Have u found the solution? I need to render in my iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

i just use [this site](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) only for watching draco/ktx gltf

Comment: Yup I know that. But the question is to redener on iOS device